# URL format - Action before or after object?

Tags: url, seo, url-design

I'm building a web application and I came across one question. Here at the office we have divided opinions so I thought it would be nice to share the question and listen to the very best (you!)

When creating the URLs for the application I was thinking about using the standard format:

For the index of the Clients module it would be:

```
www.example.com/clients
```

Then, for the details page of a client it would be:

```
www.example.com/clients/[client_slug]
```

And finally, for the update page of a client it would be:

```
www.example.com/clients/[client_slug]/update
```

Here comes the question:

What about changing the order of the parameters in the URL for the update page? It would look like this:

```
www.example.com/clients/update/[client_slug]
```

(Keeping the `[client_slug]` parameter always at the end of the URL.)

For me it makes more sense, since the URL will always follow the format "domain/module/function/object" but for some guys here it doesn't.

What you guys think? Any SEO implications or is it just a personal choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any implication in terms of ranking. If object is what people would search for, then having it early in the url like

> www.example.com/clients/[client_slug]/update

is what i would prefer because of the way the url would show up in organic results under the title.